# C# Reference to class value

Tags: c#, pointers, reference

My problem, i create one 'Class A' which updates and handles values.
'Class B' is created within 'Class A', and just needs to read the values of Class A.

Now i could create the values of class A as:

```
public static int AInt { get { return aInt; } }
static int aInt;
```

And access them within B as A.AInt.

However i could use pointers but this seems very anti-c#.

```
public class A
{
    int aInt;

    unsafe public A()
    {
        fixed(int *aPtr = &aInt)
        B b = new B(aPtr);
    }

    // Changes aInt
}

unsafe public class B
{
    int *bInt;

    public B(int *a)
    {
        bInt = a;
    }

    // Does stuff according to bInt value changes
}
```

I'm a little confused as to a better approach of supplying one class' value to another without explicitly calling an update method for the values. I feel the first example is how it should be done, but i'm from a c++ background so pointers are the norm for me.

To do pointers just seems too messy in c# as you have to change compilation flags and have to change any variable with the fixed() and mark a method/class as unsafe.

Thanks for any guidance/tips for a better solution.

Comment: Don't use `unsafe` unless you really need or you're 100% sure it's a right way to do a thing. For your example - it isn't.

Comment: Both ways work but it did seem unneccessary. Thank you for you quick reply.

Comment: What is the actual problem/question?  _"access them within B as `A.AInt`"_ seems OK.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please read it again and edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Might also be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't understand how its not clear or not a real question? I thought it was a reasonable question to ask seeing as the difference in memory between c# and c++ is quite different. Not to mention i actually researched in alternatives to this before posting. I'm not getting irate or annoyed at people i am just asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways of doing this as you have noticed.
If `aInt` will remain a static variable (read: i mean it wont change, not static type) then you can just pass it into B via a constructor or a property, or you can pass the whole object into B.

```
B b = new B(this.aInt); //this is A
```

or

```
B b = new B(this); //this is A
```

If you expect aInt to change and B to get notified then you can create an event in A and subscribe to it in B.

If you expect aInt to be different, but you will let B poll for aInt out of A you can pass a Func delegate into B and have that Func return aInt to you.

Comment: downvotes with no explanation are weird.

Comment: Ah yes, i could use a delegate to ask for the value. I didn't think of that even though i am using them for my controller input. Thanks alot.

Comment: I didnt downvote, i voted up.

Comment: @NomeSkavinski I wasn't talking about you, I was talking about whoever downvoted me first. I don't mind being downvoted as long as there is an explanation of what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather pass reference to whole `A` object, not certain property within that object:

```
public class A
{
    public int aInt;

    public A()
    {
        B b = new B(this);
    }

    // Changes aInt
}

public class B
{
    A _a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    // can use _a.aInt here
}
```

Or create an event in `A` and subscribe to that event in `B`

Comment: Would this be a viable approach even though there will only ever be One of A? A is also the entry point and is quite a large object, but as it passing a reference it wont be an issue.

Comment: If there will only be one `A` why don't make it static? With static class you don't have to pass anything, just access properties using `A.aInt`.

Comment: That is very true, seeing as B wont exist unless A exists anyway. I wish i could mark more than one answer, these are all excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do within class B, but eventuall a simple extension class is enough:

```
public class A
{
    int aInt;

    public A()
    {
        aInt = 1;
        aInt = aInt.DoSomething();
        // aInt is now 6
    }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static int DoSomething (this int value)
    {
        return value += 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, i like. Definitely keep extensions in mind for future issues, thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Extensions are a much overseen feature of C#